# Update datatable after fileupload using PrimeFaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, file-upload, primefaces, datatable

Below is my code for my file upload page and I can't figure out why when the upload is done it doesn't update my datatable with if the upload was successful or not. I could do a like a do not render til after update but don't think that is supported with the fileupload command. I did a system out on my list and it does have the values in it so the list is fully populated and ready to display but my datatable isn't showing anything? Am I missing something?

- Tomcat 7.0
- JSF 2.2.1
- Chrome/IE/Firefox
- PrimeFaces 5.0

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    template="templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">Ingest</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="metadata">



    </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content">          
<h:form>
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{ingestBean.ingestListener}"
                  label="choose" invalidFileMessage="Invalid file: "
                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xml)$/" multiple="true" update="@form">
    </p:fileUpload>

     <p:dataTable var="errors" value="#{ingestBean.errorList}" id="errorTable">
        <p:column headerText="File Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{errors.fileName}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Status">
            <h:form>
                <h:commandLink action="#{ingestBean.getErrorInfo}"
                               value="errors.status">
                    <f:param name="id" value="#{errors.id}" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:form>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Edit: After a bunch of testing and code rewriting I have got it partially working but it seems like it doesn't like to render in my template code... So I was wondering if there may be something wrong in my template code.

Template code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<f:view contentType="text/html" id="fview">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title><ui:insert name="title">Page template with PrimeFaces</ui:insert></title>
    <ui:debug />
    <f:metadata>
        <ui:insert name="metadata" />
    </f:metadata>

    <h:head>
        <style>
#leftPanel {
    z-index: 1 !important;
}

#leftPanel div {
    overflow: visible;
}

</style>


    </h:head>

    <h:body onload="statusDialog.hide();">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
        <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();"
            onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();" />
        <p:layout fullPage="true" resizeTitle="resize"
            style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="68" id="north">
                <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="202" header="Menu" id="leftPanel">
                <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit styleClass="layoutUnitCenter" position="center">
                <h:form id="mainForm">
                    <ui:insert name="content" />
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>


    </h:body>

</f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: Well to be clear multipart form data doesn't need to be included so thanks but nope and to that have to include all code not true I am able to show what is going wrong and I now it ain't me adding body is going to help anyone... And I downloading and installed tomcat on my local as well the deployed version!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of testing and deleting and rewriting like all my code I have figured out it was a stupid error with layouts and the `<f:view>` so I removed that and

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();"
            onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();" />
```

And everything seemed to work fine!